# separation of images

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, usb-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The output from my omni directional camera produces 2 fish eye images. Those images get published on /usb_cam/image_raw, while echoing the topic i found it to be an array of intensity for each pixel(my guess), I want to separate out the two images using this array.

The size of the resultant combined image is 1280 x 720, (width x height).

Any guidance !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292934/separation-of-images/) by [bala_subramanyam](https://answers.ros.org/users/35558/bala_subramanyam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a similar (maybe the same) 360 camera that uses two fisheye lenses, they are great cameras!

I recommend looking at the [cv_bridge examples](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) to manipulate the images received on a topic. This encapsulates all the processing of the raw message data so you don't have to worry about the low level representation, it will work just as well with raw or compressed images.

You can use the OpenCV to split the large image into two smaller ones, as described in the answer to [this question](http://answers.opencv.org/question/33258/how-to-cut-an-image-in-small-images-with-opencv/). Then you can use the two split images for whatever you want. If you then want to publish the split images to two separate topics you can look at this [example here](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages).

Hope this gets you going in the right direction.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bala_subramanyam](https://answers.ros.org/users/35558/bala_subramanyam/) on 2018-06-01**:
Yes, after looking at the examples I was able to separate out the images and also publish it on two different topics.
Thank You !!